# Node.js Proxy to a site in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy in node.js that will redirect my request to miniclips.com

```
   var http = require('http'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
Create your proxy server and set the target in the options.

httpProxy.createProxyServer({target:'54.192.142.49'}).listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));
```

When I run it using `localhost`  if I set the `.listen(9000)` to some port number it works fine. I go to my proxy settings and choose web proxy and select `localhost:9000`. However when I deployed this on Heroku I figured I had to change `.listen` to `.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));` I then set my proxy settings to the name-of-my-app.heroku.com and the port number to `80` but all I get is a Heroky no such app error.

`https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/heroku-error-nosuchapp/`